# Time zone transfer from GMT to UTC-4

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a datetime object as below (GMT)

```
blah    dateuno dateduo
a   29/06/2020 13:27    29/06/2020 17:44
b   19/05/2020 11:15    19/05/2020 19:25
c   8/06/2020 11:50 8/06/2020 19:51
d   9/06/2020 11:37 9/06/2020 19:38
e   20/07/2020 11:44    20/07/2020 19:47
f   21/07/2020 11:02    21/07/2020 19:08
g   23/07/2020 11:01    23/07/2020 19:05
```

How can i convert these datetimes to penssylvania times as here https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/pennsylvania

through the entire column of this dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

judging from the format in your sample, you need to cast [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) first, with kwargs `dayfirst=True` and `utc=True` (to correctly describe the input). you can then [`tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) to the appropriate time zone. Ex:

```
df['dateuno'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateuno'], dayfirst=True, utc=True)
df['dateduo'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateduo'], dayfirst=True, utc=True)

df['dateuno'] = df['dateuno'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
df['dateduo'] = df['dateduo'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')

# df
#   blah                   dateuno                   dateduo
# 0    a 2020-06-29 09:27:00-04:00 2020-06-29 13:44:00-04:00
# 1    b 2020-05-19 07:15:00-04:00 2020-05-19 15:25:00-04:00
# 2    c 2020-06-08 07:50:00-04:00 2020-06-08 15:51:00-04:00
# 3    d 2020-06-09 07:37:00-04:00 2020-06-09 15:38:00-04:00
# 4    e 2020-07-20 07:44:00-04:00 2020-07-20 15:47:00-04:00
# 5    f 2020-07-21 07:02:00-04:00 2020-07-21 15:08:00-04:00
# 6    g 2020-07-23 07:01:00-04:00 2020-07-23 15:05:00-04:00
```